# what is wrong with this realloc use

Tags: c, realloc

I'm trying to get unlimited input from user, using realloc. this is what i've done so far:

```
int getCharactersFromUser(char* arr,char terminator)
{
char c = getch();
int length =0;
while(c!=terminator)
    {
    arr = realloc(arr, sizeof (arr)*(++length));
    arr[length-1]=c;
    c = getch();
    }
return length;
}
```

i call this method with an arr like this: `char *unknownArr = calloc(0,sizeof *unknownArr);
int length = getCharactersFromUser(&unknownArr,TEMINATOR_FOR_LIST);`
here `TEMINATOR_FOR_LIST` is `eof`

Comment: Take a look at what value of `sizeof(arr)` is.

Comment: Also: if you want to use `EOF` you need an `int` for your characters. `EOF` isn't guaranteed to fit inside a `char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change the caller's copy of `arr`, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Also, `sizeof (arr)` gives you the size of `char*`; your code appears to be assuming `sizeof(char)`.  This is guaranteed to be 1, allowing your memory size calculation to be simplified.

```
int getCharactersFromUser(char** arr,char terminator)
{
    *arr = NULL; // first call to realloc will crash if `*arr` is uninitialised in caller
    char c = getch();
    int length =0;
    while(c!=terminator)
    {
        *arr = realloc(*arr, ++length);
        (*arr)[length-1]=c;
        c = getch();
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: This also seems like the kind of situation where it'd be better to realloc in powers of two, doubling each time.  (Of course, that means that more than one character can be read between reallocations.)

Comment: Instead of *arr = NULL, which has the potential for leaking, I would use if(!*arr) *arr = malloc(1); Also, what @JoshuaTaylor said. if(maxlen == curlen) *arr = realloc(*arr, (maxlen *= 2));

Comment: @JonahNelson Your version will crash if an uninitialised pointer is passed in.  The OP will have to choose which one form of misuse to guard against and document his/her function appropriately.

Comment: can u explain why do i need a pointer to a pointer? isn't a pointer to a start of address enough?

Comment: If you want the caller to be able to access `str`, you have to pass the address of their variable into `getCharactersFromUser`.  Their variable is a `char*` so the address of this is a `char**`.

Comment: now i'm calling it like this: `&unknownArr` and i get a warning "assigment makes pointer  from integer without a case".

Comment: Are you talking about the code at the bottom of your question?  I'm afraid I don't understand it.  It doesn't call `getCharactersFromUser` or match its signature.  Is it related to `getCharactersFromUser` or could it be separated into a different question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42366/discussion-between-user2719361-and-simonc)

Comment: Hmm...at a guess, have you forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>` for a definition of `calloc`?  (ansii C will assume that a function with no definition returns `int`)